# Caching downloads for offline apps

Tags: javascript, html, caching, offline, offline-caching

In my web app, I give users the ability to download various files. When trying to give the app a capability to work offline, I want to cache files that users have already downloaded, so they're able to "redownload" then, even if user is offline (in this case, file will be taken from the local cache, obviously, not from the server).

Is it possible to implement this use case? File API or Blobs, maybe?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is a little broad for a Stack Overflow answer, but its still a good question.  I will, however, point you to this resource for part of your answer: http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher This article was actually my guide to HTML5 offline mode :) but it brings me no closer to the task in question.

Comment: Then you'll have to ask a much more specific question.  What do you need cached that isn't *being* cached by that?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Specific question is in the page title - I need to cache the files that are being downloaded by users. By "downloaded" I mean binary files that user downloads by clicking links. I can't be more specific than that :)